# Determine matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T:R^2\rightarrow R^2$ by

$$
T \left( \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} x_{2} \\ x_{1}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let A be the matrix of T. What is A.

I'm having trouble understanding the textbook for solving problems like these. Please help

Comment: Map each of the basis vectors using T and put the results in the columns of the matrix. See if that works and see what it looks like then try to tell me why

Answer (score 1):

The whole statement should include:

> Compute the matrix of the linear transformation ... in the basis ...

I guess commonly one understands that on $\mathbb{R}^n$ one assume the basis they are asking is the standard one.

The algorithm is as follows

1. Evaluate $T$ on each element of the basis.
2. Expand the results as linear combinations of that basis.
3. Put the coefficients of the linear combinations above as columns of a matrix.

In our case the basis is $$e_1:=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, e_2:=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

We compute $$T\left(e_1\right)=e_2=0e_1+1e_2$$

and

$$T(e_2)=e_1=1e_1+0e_2$$

So, the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

give some example 
$$T(x,y)=(2x-y,3x+4y)\\$$
and its matrix definition is :$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\\$$ T matrix is $$ =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix} $$